# cannot get a hidden class to display with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, element, hidden

I'm working on a tic tac toe game on codepen and created my own modal. The first modal works very well and appears and disappears correctly. My second modal has a class that sets opacity and visibility so that the element is invisible just like the first. The difference is that when I remove the class that hides the element. The element doesn't appear.

I believe I have read before that this has to do with jquery not knowing about the element being hidden. I cannot remember how to fix it and couldn't find another problem like it. I want to know why the first element works and the second doesn't? I placed some of the relevant code for context and a link to the whole thing.

[This is the codepen link](http://codepen.io/skyship/pen/yOzObE)

```js
    hasWon(){
      let scores = this.scoring();
      console.log(scores);
      let win = $('.popup.end');
      for(let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
        let win = $('.end');
        if(scores[i] === 3 || scores[i] === -3){
          if(this.player === 1 && scores[i] === 3 
             || this.player === -1 && scores[i] === -3){
            win.html("<h4>Player won the Game!</h4>");
          } else {
            win.html("<h4>Computer won the Game!</h4>");
          }
          $('.back').removeClass('showEl');
          win.classList.remove("hideEl");
        }
      }
      if(this.emptyIndices().length === 0){
        win.html("<h4>It's a draw!</h4>");
        $('.back').removeClass('showEl');
        // THIS SHOULD ACTIVATE SECOND MODAL! 
        win.classList.remove("hideEl");
      }
    }
```

```css
.popup {
  font-family: 'Signika', 'sans-serif';
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 270px;
  background: #d0e6d0;
  border: 6px solid #97b097;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1000px 2000px rgba(228, 241, 228, 0.9);
  border-radius: 60px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.popup h4 {
  padding-top: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  left: 13%;
  position: absolute;
}

.hideEl {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.showEl {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup end hideEl">
  <h4>Ending Message</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `win.removeClass` instead of `win.classList.remove` just like you did in the previous line? https://jsfiddle.net/jbhb1wc7/

Comment: Why not just use css style `hidden` and just use `Element.classList.toggle('hidden');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jquery` code is awesome and perfect, except there was problem with `html`. You did not close the `div` with `class` - `.popup.who` which is why the `div` with `class` - `.popup.end` would end up wrapping withing `.popup.who` - `div` and after finishing with first modal when you `hide` `.popup.who` - `div`, it actually hides the `.popup.end` too, since the same was wrapped within the `.popup.who` - `div`.

**Faulty Code**

```
<div class="popup who">
  <h4>Do you want to play as X or O?</h4>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary choose_x player">X</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary choose_o player">O</button>
<div> <!--This here wasn't ending the div-->

<div class="popup end hideEl">
  <h4>Ending Message</h4>
</div>
```

**Corrected code**

```
<div class="popup who">
  <h4>Do you want to play as X or O?</h4>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary choose_x player">X</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary choose_o player">O</button>
</div>

<div class="popup end hideEl">
  <h4>Ending Message</h4>
</div>
```

## [`UPDATED CODEPEN`](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/yJybgX)

Comment: Lol.. Thanks.. Happy coding.. :)